# How do I sharpen a bitmap image that has been enlarged from a small size? Is it even possible?

Tags: gimp, resize, blur

I am trying to find a way of sharpening the following image with GIMP:

[image: Blurred image]

Is there any approach on doing this? Is it even possible?.

Comment: What have you tried? What tutorials have you looked at? What is not working? If you show more effort you're likely to get a better response

Comment: @ZachSaucier dude, relax, what if I have done nothing? you are not willing to help then? anyway: I have followed [this](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Smart_Sharpening/) obtaining [this](http://s13.postimg.org/krewbzgh3/lab_compose.png) as a result. There are more tutorials, but there are all alike.

Comment: I would redraw this using a vector application. It is simple shapes with gradients and shadows applied.

Comment: @Scott Completely redraw it?. I did tried to trace the bitmap using Inkscape, the outputs wasn't really satisfactory. Your advice is to redo it?

Comment: No amount of sharpening or any other automated process can make this image look good.

Comment: Hans, if your question does not show what you have tried so far, then there is the possibility that it will be put on hold. See http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/should-extremely-basic-how-to-do-this-in-software-x-questions-be-off-topic

Comment: I did **not** suggest *tracing*. I posted **redraw**.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: @Hans Stack Exchange is not Google. Go to Google first, come here last. Show you have made some effort. Telling a veteran user to relax, when he is just trying to get you to do what you should have already done, is a good way to start off on the wrong foot here.

Comment: @neuronet I've been in plenty of stackexchange sites, I know how does it work. I'm not willing to make a big deal out of this. If something is found in google I expect to find it here, that is what this is for. You can be sure most of the things here can be found in google as well, can't really see your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the correct answer to your question is 'you can't'. As Joonas mentioned in his comment, it's going to be nigh impossible to create something good-looking with automated processes like sharpening tools. Those will only emphasise on the blockiness of the image I suppose you're trying to get rid of.

Tracing (as in converting this bitmap to a vector image) is most probably not going to work either, the tracing algorithms aren't going to be handling the image correctly. There's lots of artefacts in the image because of it being enlarged from a very small size, and the tracing tools won't ignore those.

Your best option is therefore what Scott says: recreate the image. If you know how to handle a vector program like Inkscape or Adobe Illustrator, this shouldn't be too hard a task. Even within Photoshop or the GIMP alone you could have a go at recreating this and succeed rather well.

Comment: To be honest in this particular case there is a trick that MIGHT do an acceptable job. hard to say i would need the original image to incrementally attack the problem.

Comment: @joojaa I thought there was a way of doing so, now you give me hope. What do you mean by "original image". Can't you just download the posted image?.

Comment: @Vincent I did follow you advice, [this is the result](http://s30.postimg.org/udmc2gwip/app_jpg.png) however I am still really interested in any way of sharpen this kind of images.